# Recoding multiple values in a column using an "ifelse" statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm new to using "R" (used to using SPSS), I am having trouble recoding values for a variable, given multiple responses or cases for that variable. I am trying to use an "ifelse" function to achieve this, but I cannot make the function work for modifying more than two values for the variables. I want to recode responses for a variable with multiple cases. Currently the data includes #'s 1, 2, 3, 4 and I want to recode these numbers like this:

- (1=0.6)
- (2=1.2)
- (3=2.5)
- (4=1.8)

I am trying to use an "ifelse" function to achieve this, but I cannot make the function work for modifying more than two different values for the specific variable.

```
ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 <- ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==1, 0.6, ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==2, 1.2,
ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==3, 2.5, ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==4, 1.8))
```

I would like all of the data in the column for variable Predilection_1 to be recoded with 0.6, 1.2, 2.5, 1.8, but I keep getting the error: argument "no" is missing, with no default. Any ideas of how I can modify this code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The last if else  ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==4, 1.8) is missing the else value  ifelse(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1==4, 1.8, "???")

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to see the problem if you [add more white space](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html#long-lines) to the code.

```
ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 <- ifelse(
  ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 == 1, 
  0.6, 
  ifelse(
    ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 == 2, 
    1.2, 
    ifelse(
      ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 == 3, 
      2.5, 
      ifelse(
        ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1 == 4, 
        1.8
      )
    )
```

From this you may be able to see two things: the final `ifelse()` only has two arguments rather than three, and there are two closing brackets missing. The first thing is what's causing the error message: the missing third argument is the 'no' argument that R is complaining is missing. You should set this argument to whatever you want the value of `Predilection_1` to be if the original value is not one of 1, 2, 3 or 4. If you don't have a value in mind, you should probably set it to `NA`.

You should also add the two missing closing brackets, or the code will not run.

The difficulty in reading nested `ifelse()` functions is one reason why the [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) package includes the [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) function. You can use this to produce much shorter code:

```r
ChildPABase19_test <- mutate(ChildPABase19_test, Predilection_1 = case_when(
  Predilection_1 == 1 ~ 0.6,
  Predilection_1 == 2 ~ 1.2,
  Predilection_1 == 3 ~ 2.5,
  Predilection_1 == 4 ~ 1.8,
  TRUE ~ NA_real_
))
```

The examples in the [documentation for `case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) do a fairly good job of explaining the syntax, if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(expss)
ChildPABase19_test = data.frame(Predilection_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
recode(ChildPABase19_test$Predilection_1) = c(1 ~ 0.6, 2 ~ 1.2, 3 ~ 2.5, 4 ~ 1.8)

ChildPABase19_test
#    Predilection_1
# 1            0.6
# 2            1.2
# 3            2.5
# 4            1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code using `dplyr` package may help:

```
require(dplyr)
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
transform_rule <- list(
    "1" = "0.6",
    "2" = "1.2",
    "3" = "2.5",
    "4" = "1.8"
)
x_recoded <- as.numeric(recode(x, !!!transform_rule))
```